# Chances of at least one each of two values on X dice

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

I'm trying to work out the chance of rolling at least one each of 2 different values (say for example at least one 1 and at least one 2) on x dice. I'm not concerned about the totals, it's just the discrete values, so a success would simply be one or more of value A AND one or more of value B. I can't figure out how to represent this as a formula, the only way I can solve it is to draw out the sample space, which becomes unworkable as the number of dice (or sides on the dice) increase. Is there a simple way of representing this problem as a formula?

Comment: Try Inclusion Exclusion.

Comment: Yes.  Use the inclusion-exclusion principle.  Take the probability of having avoided rolling any $1$'s, the probability of having avoided rolling any $2$'s, and the probability of having avoided any $1$'s and $2$'s, and combine this into an answer

Comment: Thanks very much. So essentially 1 - (chance of no As)  - (chance of no Bs) + (chance of no As or Bs)?